# "At the beginning of the end step" versus "Until end of turn"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Deceiver of Form](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deceiver%20of%20Form) is used to copy my [Biovisionary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Biovisionary), does his "at the beginning of the end step" ability resolve before Deceiver of Form's "until end of turn" ability expires, thus making Deceiver of Form a fairly easy way to "win the game"?

Comment: I don't know if getting Deceiver forms with 4+ other creatures out and Biovisionary on the top would be called fairly easy.

Comment: i can typically play deceiver on turn 4 and i already have 3+ scions plus the creatures that spawned them

Comment: it's not super easy but it's easier than playing 4 of them or playing one and 3 clones.

Comment: So you rely just on the ability to cycle through your entire deck in order to get a Biovisonary on the top?

Comment: i have a few sylvan tutors and other ways to get it on top the point of the question was just to see if beggin and end would resolve separately

Comment: given that it's blue and green it stands to reason the majority of my deck would then be control and deck thinning mana search cards. so it's plausible at least, just a fun concept i thought of when i pulled a deceiver

Comment: Mirrorweave is also an easy way to do it. Be careful though that when your opponent also has 4 creatures he will win if you cast Mirrorweave on your turn

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  "At the beginning of the end step" abilities trigger at, well, the beginning of the end step, while "until end of turn effects" expire at the beginning of the cleanup step, which is after the end step.  Thus, Biovisionary's ability will trigger and resolve while all your creatures are still Biovisionaries.

Comprehensive Rules references:

> 512.1. The ending phase consists of two steps: end and cleanup. *[This appears to be the closest thing to an explicit statement that end precedes cleanup.]*
>
> 514.2. Second, the following actions happen simultaneously [during the cleanup step]: all damage marked on permanents (including phased-out permanents) is removed and all “until end of turn” and “this turn” effects end. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.